# How can I debug the below Hacker Rank challenge that uses Bitwise Operators?

Tags: c

This program just requires basic knowledge of AND, OR and XOR operations.

N=5, K=2, S={1,2,3,4,5}

Sample Input:

```
5 4
```

Sample Output:

```
2
3
3
```

Input Format

The only line contains space-separated integers, n and k, respectively.

Output Format

The first line of output contains the maximum possible value of `a & b`.

The second line of output contains the maximum possible value of `a | b`.

The second line of output contains the maximum possible value of `a ^ b`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, n, c, d, e, max = 0, k;
    int high = 0, more = 0, large = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (i < j)
            {
                c = i & j;
                d = i | j;
                e = i ^ j;

                if ( c < k && d < k && e < k)
                {
                    if (c > max)
                    { 
                        max=c;
                    }
                    if (d > large)
                    {
                        large=d;
                    }
                    if (e > more)
                    {
                        more = e;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", max);
    printf("%d\n", large);
    printf("%d", more);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I fix this code? My test case is passed when is entered 5 and 4 as inputs. But when I entered 454 and 67, my test case failed. I am getting error only when I am printing `max`.

For full and clear description of my problem visit https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bitwise-operators-in-c/problem

Comment: It's not clear the meaning of _"maximum possible value of `a & b`"_ because all those operations are commutative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(c<k&&d<k&&e<k)
```

This line checks if c, d, and e are all less than k at the same time. However, you want to consider each one of them separately.

Say x & y is the maximum value less than k. This does not necessarily mean that x | y and x XOR y are less than k as well.

Side note: I suggest you use better naming system for your variables 
to make your code more readable.

ie: max_and, max_or, max_xor instead of max, large, and more

cur_and, cur_and, cur_xor instead of c, d, e

Comment: Thank you so much bro.Your analysis is amaizing.Thank you for suggesting me good readability of code.